# As a developer who previously published a listing, how can I delete the listing from the G Suite Marketplace?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

As a developer who previously published a listing, how can I delete the listing from the G Suite Marketplace? (The listing is for an old app.)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't really tried deleting my own listing (cause I paid for it) but you can try to [Delete your G Suite account](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6313602?hl=en):

> **Delete your G Suite account**
>
> 1. Sign in to your Google Admin console with your G Suite email address (for example, you@yourdomain.com), not your Gmail address. If
>      you’re signed into a different Google account, you can switch
>      accounts.
> 2. If you’re prompted to set up billing, click Do this later.
> 3. Export any user data you want to save.
> 4. Delete any Marketplace applications you've added.
> 5. From the Admin console dashboard, go to Billing.
> 6. Next to your subscription, click Actions and select Cancel subscription.
> 7. Click Continue.
> 8. Check to the box to confirm that you want to delete your account. Once your account is deleted: Your G Suite account and all user
>      accounts are deleted. You won’t be able to sign in to Google services
>      with this account. All data is deleted.
> 9. Click Delete My Domain to delete your account.